# Adding Different Icons to each column of row at beginning inside the table

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, html-table

I know I can use some HTML Elements like `<img>` tag, but I have 50+ rows in the table, and icons are 10, let's take an example, I have 25 rows in table which are related apple and 25 rows in table which related to oranges and all rows are mixed up, So what is the best way to add Apple and orange icons,

I Got A Objective-C Code Which My Work With My Requirements but Need it for Website

```
cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:    
              [NSString stringWithFormat:@"icon%d.png",indexPath.row]];
```

can tell the script what icons need to be added on which row numbers.

What is the Best Way to do this?

Comment: I'm confused - the code you've added is ObjectiveC, as used in native iOS applications. It's not at all related to JS and is certainly not something you would use on the web. Please add the relevant code you are using to create the table to the question

Comment: @Rory McCrossan Ok, I got this code on a website, I thought its a javascript. but I think this is a thing What I wanted but need to add it in my website

Answer (score 0):

I have updated below code, see example below it will help you

```
  <table>
      <tr><td id="cell-0">1</td>
          <td>2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr><td id="cell-0">2</td>
          <td>2</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <script>  
    var i = 1;
    document.querySelectorAll('#cell-0').forEach(function(std) {
         i++; 
         std.innerHTML = '<img src="'+ i + '.png">'; 
    });
    </script>
```

Comment: @ rajesh Please Explain How this JS script Works,

Comment: @Varun - if my answer helpful than just give me a your valuable vote - thanks